# source code of dojo.require function

Tags: javascript, dojo

All, Forgive me I am a beginner of Dojo,  I download Dojo base from the [here](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.3/dojo.js.uncompressed.js). And trying to find the define of dojo.require function to see how it is implemented. Unfortunately didn't found anything useful about it . Could someone please help me out ? thanks.

Comment: it's in dojo.js. it's NOT an easy read...

Comment: @rambocoder I searched with the keywords `require` in the dojo.js, didn't found any js function named like it.

Comment: So... is your question solved? Your edits look like they're answering your question, so maybe you should add this as an answer in stead, making it clear to everyone that this question has been answered.

Comment: @DimitriM :) The question still remains is I didn't understand why `require` point to `req`.

Comment: @DimitriM The hardest part of Dojo I think is the Dojo AMD api(define.declare.require).

Comment: True, but there are a few reasons why it's hard. First of all, Dojo is compliant with old (non-AMD) versions which introduced a lot of legacy code. Then second, the Dojo AMD loader works on many environments including Node.js. Obviously it has another way of publishing stuff, so the function has to be wrapped.

Comment: @DimitriM Thanks you for telling more about it. Another thing I think is JavaScript closure. Sometime the context of it makes me confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug the code and found the require function point to below code.

```
    // this will be the global require function; define it immediately so we can start hanging things off of it
            req = function(
                config,       //(object, optional) hash of configuration properties
                dependencies, //(array of commonjs.moduleId, optional) list of modules to be loaded before applying callback
                callback      //(function, optional) lambda expression to apply to module values implied by dependencies
            ){
                return contextRequire(config, dependencies, callback, 0, req);
            },
...

// the loader can be defined exactly once; look for global define which is the symbol AMD loaders are
    // *required* to define (as opposed to require, which is optional)
    if(global.define){
        if( 1 ){
            signal(error, makeError("defineAlreadyDefined", 0));
        }
        return;
    }else{
        global.define = def;
        global.require = req;//define the global variable require and define .
        if( 0 ){
            require = req;
        }
    }
```

And also found something else interesting.
If dojo.require a js file like below. in my test the js file location in the `util/utiltest.js` .

```
require(
            ["dojo/ready", "util/utiltest"],
            function (ready, util) {
                ready(function () {
                    var id = "selected_text";
                    util.setRed(id);
                });
            });
```

the code in the utiltest.js is :

```
define("util/utiltest",["dojo/dom", 'require'], function (dom) {
    return {
        setRed: function (id) {
            dom.byId(id).style.color = "red";
        }
    };
});
```

Actually Dojo will create the script tag to load it in the page.

[image]

Hope this can be helpful to you. thanks.